# Gatsby MDX not rendering properly

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, mdx

I am making a website which has a blog. I am using Gatsby and following [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/mdx/) tutorial. I figured out how to use JSX components in MDX such as my `Layout` component which I wish to apply to all pages - blogs and non-blogs. Here is the code in my MDX file right now:

```
import Layout from "../components/layout";

<Layout>

# Testing header 1

## Testing header 2 and math
$f(x) = 2$

</Layout>
```

What I see on the website is this:
[image]

The markdown-specific syntax is not being applied (e.g. headers and LaTeX). I have properly installed all the packages listed in the tutorial I linked:

[image]

My `gatsby-config.ts` is also properly updated with `gatsby-plugin-mdx` and `gatsby-source-filesystem`.

[image]

I don't understand why the markdown syntax and the math is not being rendered properly. I tried it even without wrapping the MDX in a JSX component as I've done below but that didn't work either.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. Actually it *was* rendering properly but I just didn't have any styles. I did not realize that I had to write my own styles and the MDX just took care of rendering markdown but not styling it.

Here is my [full discussion](https://github.com/orgs/mdx-js/discussions/2387#discussioncomment-7416980) with a helpful maintainer of the mdx-js forum who explained this to me